# How I can align widgets in GTK 3

Tags: c, gtk

```
box1=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,3);
align=gtk_alignment_new(1,0,0,0);
my=gtk_button_new_with_label("HELLO");
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame),my);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box1),frame);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),box1);
```

I must write all this code to align a button on the left up of the window or is a easier way.If someone can give me more information about containers of GTK because I understand  hard the reference .

Before using Glade I want to see how things works. Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the documentation for [GtkAlignment](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html) notes in Gtk3 there is usually no need to use it as the same effect can be achieved by setting the [halign](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--halign) and [margin](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--margin), [hexpand](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--hexpand) properties of the widget that you wish to align.

To have the button in the top left you would set `halign` and `valign` to `GTK_ALIGN_START`.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: As noted by [jku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2241569/jku), `GtkHBox`, `GtkVBox`, and `GtkTable` are now deprecated, and [GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkGrid.html) should be used instead. `GtkAlignment` is also deprecated, and the properties given in the [answer by Phillip Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22281550/369450) should be used instead.

---

I think you meant [`gtk_alignment_new(0,0,0,0)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html#gtk-alignment-new) to align to the left. But without knowing about the other widgets within the window, that looks good to me. That's how you align.

The basic layout containers in GTK are:

- [GtkFixed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFixed.html) which allows widgets to be absolutely positioned.

  ```
  +----------------------------+
  |                   Widget 3 |
  | Widget 2                   |
  |              Widget 1      |
  |                            |
  +----------------------------+
  ```
- [GtkHBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHBox.html) allows widgets the be positioned horizontally:

  ```
  +--------+-----+
  | Widget | ... |
  +--------+-----+
  ```
- [GtkVBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkVBox.html) allows widgets to be positioned vertically:

  ```
  +--------+
  | Widget |
  +--------+
  |  ...   |
  +--------+
  ```
- [GtkTable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTable.html) allows for a grid or table layout.

  ```
  +--------+-----+
  | Widget | ... |
  +--------+-----+
  |  ...   | ... |
  +--------+-----+
  ```

In addition to those containers, there's also [GtkAlignment](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAlignment.html) which allows you to control the alignment of a widget within its allotted space.

[GTK+ layout management](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtklayoutmanagement/) is a decent tutorial providing working examples of the different layout containers.

Comment: For reference, the linked tutorial and parts of this answer are obsolete or rapidly becoming so: Table, VBox and HBox have been deprecated in favor of Grid (or Box but Grid does everything a Box can do). Alignment will be deprecated in 3.14 since Widget properties already do everything Alignment does.