# How to align elements with GTK library in C/C++

Tags: c++, alignment, gtk

I'm getting some problem with GTK+ library in C/C++.
I have a simple GTK table where the first and the third column contain a labels with descriptions. In particular the first one is the name of a test that is in execution. The third is a description of the running state of the test.

The second column contains progress bars, one for each row, and as you can see from the image they are not aligned with the labels on the same row.

How can I fix this problem? Here's a short and reproducible example that shows my problem:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(win)); 
g_signal_connect (win, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit),NULL);
GtkWidget *names[7], *states[7], *bars[7];
GtkWidget *table = gtk_table_new (7, 3, TRUE);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ ){

    names[i] = gtk_label_new( std::string("Name" + std::to_string(i)).c_str() );
    states[i] = gtk_label_new("Waiting Mode");
    bars[i] = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), names[i] , 0, 1, i, i+1);     
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), bars[i] , 1, 2, i, i+1);      
    gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), states[i] , 2, 3, i, i+1);        
}

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), table);
gtk_widget_show_all (win);
gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

The GUI that you will obtain is this one:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvohX.png)

Comment: I can't, I need at least 10 reputation to add directly a screenshot

Comment: Ok, that's right. It would also help if you could add a minimal and reproducible example (in code) that reproduces your issue. Withouht any code, we can't help.

Comment: I've added an example that show my problem, I've also refreshed the image :)

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272446/how-i-can-align-widgets-in-gtk-3 answer your question? Please also specify the version of the Gtk library that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vertical alignment of your progress bar widgets using [`gtk_widget_valign_set`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.set_halign.html). Using your provided example:

```c
    // ...

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++ ){
    
        names[i] = gtk_label_new(std::string("Name" + std::to_string(i)).c_str());
        states[i] = gtk_label_new("Waiting Mode");
        bars[i] = gtk_progress_bar_new();

        // Align vertically in the table:
        gtk_widget_set_valign(bars[i], GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);

        gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), names[i]  , 0, 1, i, i+1);     
        gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), bars[i]   , 1, 2, i, i+1);      
        gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), states[i] , 2, 3, i, i+1);        
    }
    
    // ...
```

Using Gtkmm 3.24, this yields:

[image]

Since you seem to be already using C++, I would recommend checking [Gtkmm](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/), which is a C++ wrapper around Gtk+.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [`GtkAlign`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/enum.Align.html). A C example:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *win = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_fullscreen (GTK_WINDOW (win));
  g_autofree gchar *label_text = NULL;
  GtkWidget *names[7], *states[7], *bars[7];
  GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new ();
  for (gint32 i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    label_text = g_strdup_printf ("Name %d", i);
    names[i] = gtk_label_new (label_text);
    states[i] = gtk_label_new ("Waiting Mode");
    bars[i] = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_widget_set_valign(bars[i], GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), names[i] , 0, i, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), bars[i] , 1, i, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), states[i] , 2, i, 1, 1);
  }

  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (win), grid);
  gtk_widget_show (win);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Good documentation for alignment of `GtkBox` or `GtkGrid` is still GTK 3's, but it is also applicable to GTK 4: [GtkBox versus GtkGrid: sizing](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/ch30s02.html)
.
[The effect screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zfJU.png).